# Get broadcast receiver to get cellular sim network connectivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am currently working on SMS related app. Need to detect when phone is on no service area and phone when came to service area send pending messages. Right now i am able to find all network/WIFI/mobile data connectivity receiver but i want a receiver which is called when mobile get mobile cellular sim network back. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there exist such broadcast when the cellular connectivity is resumed.

You can see how Android's MMS code handles MMS messages that weren't sent here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master/src/com/android/mms/transaction/RetryScheduler.java

Specifically, they set an AlarmManager to retry again after some time, and if there were X failed attempts they mark the message as undlivered in the messaging DB:

```
long retryAt = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PendingMessages.DUE_TIME));
Intent service = new Intent(TransactionService.ACTION_ONALARM, null, context, TransactionService.class);
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, service, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, retryAt, operation);
```

Also, you should register to the `BOOT_RECEIVED` broadcast, and check for any failed sms messages that needs to be retried.